# Increment a column if a row already exists with the same values

Tags: mysql, sql

This one's a bit too tricky for my SQL-foo.

What I need to do is insert a new row (which contains 3 columns), *unless* a row already exists where two of those values are the same, and if it does exist, I need to increment the third value on that row.

Imagine the two values being a relationship (a, b) and the third value being the relationships's strength (which increases with every ocurrence of that relationship).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can we assume that (a, b) is unique for this table?  In particular, can we put a unique index on it?

Comment: @tloach Yes, (a, b) is always unique for this table, value B is unique (the second member of the relationship), value A may appear multiple times.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
INSERT
INTO    a_b (a, b, strength)
VALUES  ($a, $b, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE  strength = strength + 1
```

Make sure you have a `UNIQUE (a, b)` or `PRIMARY KEY (a, b)` constraint on the table

Comment: That works with a single value, but what if I want to check if a row already exists with the same two values?

Comment: @Filipe: if you have `(1, 1)` in the table, inserting `(2, 1)` or `(1, 2)` will insert, but inserting `(1, 1)` will update. Isn't it what you wanted?